# MVVM WPF one item source two comboboxes different properties, second property does not get set initially

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Currently when I bind two combo boxes to the same item source 
and I set the SelectedItem of the combo boxes to two separate properties
and I set the SelectedIndex of the combo boxes to two different indexes

After the UI loads 
The Combo boxes load and show the correct indexes
However, the property for Person in the viewModel is set but the property for PersonTwo is not set until I select a different item manually from the second combo box.

If I then make a separate but identical list and I bind the itemsource of the second combobox to it then the data for PersonTwo is set to the selectedIndex

I've tried searching to better understand what is happening but I'm not any closer to finding an answer. I don't understand why this is the behavior when both combo boxes use the same item source.

Smallest working example:
Model

```
namespace WpfApp1
{
    public class Person
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }
}
```

ViewModel

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    public class GenericViewModel
    {
        public GenericViewModel()
        {
            People = new List<Person>();
            Person personToMakeList = null;
            People.Add(personToMakeList = new Person(){Age = 10,Id=1,Name="John"});
            People.Add(personToMakeList = new Person() { Age = 20, Id = 2, Name = "Amber" });
            People.Add(personToMakeList = new Person() { Age = 30, Id = 3, Name = "Amy" });
            People.Add(personToMakeList = new Person() { Age = 40, Id = 4, Name = "Joey" });
            Person = new Person();
            PersonTwo = new Person();
        }
        public Person Person { get; set; }
        public List<Person> People { get; set; }
        public Person PersonTwo { get; set; }
    }
}
```

View

```
 <Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid>
    <Grid.DataContext>
        <local:GenericViewModel/>
    </Grid.DataContext>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <StackPanel>
            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding People}"
                      SelectedIndex="0"
                      SelectedItem="{Binding Person}"
                      DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <TextBlock Text="Person One"></TextBlock>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="Age: "/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Person.Age}"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="Id: "/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Person.Id}"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="Name: "/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Person.Name}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel>
            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding People}"
                      SelectedIndex="3"
                      SelectedItem="{Binding PersonTwo}"
                      DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <TextBlock Text="Person Two"></TextBlock>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="Age: "/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding PersonTwo.Age}"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="Id: "/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding PersonTwo.Id}"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="Name: "/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding PersonTwo.Name}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I tested your code, and everything is perfectly working: two `ComboBoxes` binded to the same `List`, but their `SelectedItem` binded to two different `Person`. `PersonOne` will show the `SelectedItem` of the first `ComboBox`, and `PersonTwo` the `SelectedItem` of the second `ComboBox`. What do you want to do, or what behaviour did you expected?

Comment: Your view model should implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface and fire the PropertyChanged event from the Person and PersonTwo setters. You should also not rely on the order in which properties are set by the XAML parser. Setting a ComboBox's SelectedIndex and SelectedItem at the same time may lead to different results. Better don't set SelectedIndex at all, and use `PersonTwo = People[3]` in the view model constructor.

Comment: The original code does implement INotifyPropertyChanged, I should have mentioned that or added it in to my snippets above anyway, this was the smallest sample I could make that had the same described behavior. I want to understand what is happening when the xaml attempting to set the properties especially since the behavior seems consistent that the second property will not be set if the first property is set using the same bindings.